# Compute $\oint\limits_{\partial\Sigma} \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\,$

Tags: line-integrals, greens-theorem

Assume $ \partial\Sigma$ is a positively oriented, piecewise smooth, simple closed curve in a plane and let $ \Sigma$ be the region bounded by $ \partial\Sigma$ containing $(0,0)$, then compute $$\oint\limits_{\partial\Sigma} \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\,$$

---

The functions are not defined at the origin, so we can't use Green's theorem, but:

Let $B_\epsilon(0,0):=\left\{(x,y):x^2+y^2 \le \epsilon^2\right\}$ be a circle centered at the origin, and $ \Sigma_\epsilon=\Sigma \setminus B_\epsilon(0,0)$, so I think this is true to claim that $$\partial \Sigma_\epsilon=\partial \Sigma \cup \partial B_\epsilon(0,0)$$

So:

$$0=\iint \limits_{\Sigma_\epsilon}0 \; dxdy=\oint\limits_{\partial\Sigma_\epsilon} \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\,=\oint\limits_{\partial \Sigma} \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\,+\oint\limits_{\partial B_\epsilon(0,0)} \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\,$$$$=\oint\limits_{\partial \Sigma} \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\,+\oint\limits_{x^2+y^2 = \epsilon^2} \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\,$$

How to continue?

Comment: You're forgetting about the orientations.

Comment: @  peek-a-boo, why?

Comment: Imagine for a second that $\Sigma$ is the punctured disk of radius $1$. Then, sketch $\Sigma_{\epsilon}$, and sketch the orientations of the boundary. What do you observe?

Comment: @ peek-a-boo, I think that plus sign should be a minus one, but the problem is that I don't know how to sketch the orientations of the boundary.

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 = \epsilon^2$ is a circle. Try evaluate the integral there using polar coordinates... About orientation on boundary, if you walk along the boundary in correct direction, the region will be located on your left-hand side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B\varepsilon(0,0)$ is a disk with radius $\varepsilon$ and centered at the origin.  Then, on $\Sigma\setminus B_\varepsilon(0,0)$ the functions $L=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ and $M=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ are continuously differentiable and Green's Theorem applies.  Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\Sigma\setminus B_\varepsilon(0,0)}\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right)\,dx\,dy =\oint_{\partial \Sigma}(L\,dx+M\,dy) -\oint_{\partial B_\varepsilon(0,0)}(L\,dx+M\,dy)\tag1
\end{align}$$

where the minus sign on the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is a consequence of the orientation of the line integrals that bound $\Sigma\setminus B_\varepsilon(0,0)$.

It is easy to show that the integrand of the integral on the left-hand side of $(1)$ is identically $0$.  Hence, we see that

$$\oint_{\partial \Sigma}(L\,dx+M\,dy) =\oint_{\partial B_\varepsilon(0,0)}(L\,dx+M\,dy)\tag2$$

We can parameterize the integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ with $x=\varepsilon \cos(\phi)$ and $y=\varepsilon \sin(\phi)$, to find that

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{\partial B_\varepsilon(0,0)}(L\,dx+M\,dy)&=\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{\varepsilon \sin(\phi)\varepsilon \sin(\phi)}{\varepsilon^2}+\frac{\varepsilon \cos(\phi) \varepsilon \cos(\phi)}{\varepsilon^2}\right)\,d\phi\\\\
&=2\pi
\end{align}$$

from which we conclude that

$$\oint_{\partial \Sigma }\left(\frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}\right)=2\pi$$

Comment: What if the LHS was not zero?

Comment: @masaheb If the integral over $\Sigma$ is not $0$, then the line integrals are not equal.

Comment: If I was given $\partial \Sigma$, then could I just parameterize the curve and then compute the line integral?

Comment: Well, conceptually that is correct.  But as you know, computing an integral in closed form is not always possible.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to write this as a complex integral.  Take
$$\begin{eqnarray}
z &=& x + \mathrm i \ y \\
\mathrm d z &=& \mathrm d x + \mathrm i\ \mathrm d y \\
\mathrm d \overline z &=& \mathrm d x - \mathrm i\ \mathrm d y.\end{eqnarray}$$

Then $x^2 + y^2 = z \ \overline z$ and $$ x \ \mathrm d y - y \ \mathrm d x = \frac1{2 \mathrm i}(\overline z \ \mathrm d z - z \ \mathrm d \overline z).$$
Now use [Cauchy’s integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) to evaluate your integral. (Use the substitution $z \leftarrow \overline z$ for the “conjugate” part.)  The result is $\pi + \pi$.

Comment: (+1) Clear and concise and shows the connection between Green's Theorem in the plane and Cauchy's Integral Formula.